# Azure Durable Function is Pending, How To Triage?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an azure durable function that I've written.  Sometimes when testing it, it goes to "pending" status and I have no idea why.

I run my Azure function out of Visual Studio and just click the green "run" arrow.  The compilation finishes by loading a console that has a little azure function ascii logo and then spits output of the azure function process.

I tried attaching to my localhost dev storage using the Azure Storage Explorer tool and the process outlined here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows#work-with-local-development-storage

When I connect to the local storage account, I open the "tables" drop down and it is empty.

So... How are you supposed to triage "weird stuff" that happens in localhost azure functions?

Comment: on your functiom app, have you enable loggin using app insights ? you may find some useful information in app insights

Comment: this is on localhost

Comment: yes but you can still send data to app insights for dev